# trying to get a src tag containing specific word

Tags: jquery, ajax, regex, wikipedia-api

i have an ajax request to wikipedia and am targeting the info box in order to get and append a flag image for a user inputted city. here's the call:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org//w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page='+city+'&prop=images&prop=text',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            var readData = $('<div>' + response.parse.text["*"] + '</div>');
            var box = readData.find('.infobox');

            flagURL = box.find('img').first().attr('src');

            $('#flag').append('<div><img src="'+ flagURL +'"/>')
        }
    });
```

the problem is that targeting the first img sometimes works, sometimes not. it's impossible to know if the flag image is 1st/2nd/etc for different city pages. i've tried chaining a .get('Flag'), .contains('Flag'), and .match with a 'Flag' regex to the end of the flagURL, as well as selecting nth img child and using jquery's :eq selector, but nothing seems to do the trick. i'm thinking a regex is the only surefire bet, but have never used regexes in jQuery.

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted as if it works for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jquery contains selector for this

```
$( "img[src*='Flag']" )
```

So above will search images whoes src contains flag

Comment: i've tried using it solely as a selector and within both find and attr methods and none of them seem to work. am i missing the right way?